# Book on Vectors

Tags: resource-recommendations, vectors, mathematics, geometry

Can someone recommend a good book on vectors for High school and pre University students. Nothing too complex but enough for first year physic students and helps cover the basics and helps you in applying them. I have tried checking similiar post but they were mostly about string theory and special relativity which is not my level yet.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I was gonna ask there as well but I just thought since I be using it in physics more I would just ask here

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend *[A Student's Guide to Vectors and Tensors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009019VBY)*. Very readable and suitable for a first year physics student. You can skip the tensors part if it doesn't interest you.

Comment: Hi thanks for your recommendation I will definitely try it.